# PostgreSQL: how to convert "PIVOT" from T-SQL to PLPGSQL procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, pivot, plpgsql

I would like to convert a stored procedure from T-SQL to PL/PGSQL.
Here is the T-SQL code

```
SELECT NO_PTF, coalesce(1, 0) as RISK_1, coalesce(2, 0) as RISK_2, coalesce(3, 0) as RISK_3, coalesce(4, 0) as RISK_4
    FROM (
            SELECT D.NO_PTF, C.NB_DEG_RSQ, D.MT_DEM/100 as MT_DEM
                FROM public.TB_Demande      D
                    INNER JOIN
                    public.TB_Compartiment C ON D.ID_CPA = C.ID_CPA
                                                AND D.MC_UTL = 'F3000'
                                                AND C.IN_ACT = true
            ) Q
    PIVOT (SUM(Q.MT_DEM) FOR Q.NB_DEG_RSQ IN (1, 2, 3, 4)) as PVT
    )
```

I tried to replace PIVOT by crosstab. But i have an error. Here is my PL/PGSQL code

```
SELECT NO_PTF, coalesce(1, 0) as RISK_1, coalesce(2, 0) as RISK_2, coalesce(3, 0) as RISK_3, coalesce(4, 0) as RISK_4
    FROM (
            SELECT D.NO_PTF, C.NB_DEG_RSQ, D.MT_DEM/100 as MT_DEM
                FROM public.TB_Demande      D
                    INNER JOIN
                    public.TB_Compartiment C ON D.ID_CPA = C.ID_CPA
                                                AND D.MC_UTL = 'F3000'
                                                AND C.IN_ACT = true
            ) Q
    crosstab (SUM(Q.MT_DEM) FOR Q.NB_DEG_RSQ IN (1, 2, 3, 4)) as PVT
```

Someone have an idea about the rigth way to use crosstab here?

Comment: `coalesce(1, 0)` makes no sense. That's the same as `1`

Comment: yes it always return 1. But my question is about convert the Pivot to crosstab or any other solution. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure I understand the PIVOT syntax, but typically this is way easier in Postgres using a filtered aggregation, not the somewhat clumsy `crosstab()` function.

I *think* this should be equivalent:

```
select no_ptf,  
       sum(mt_dem) filter (where NB_DEG_RSQ = 1) as risk_1,
       sum(mt_dem) filter (where NB_DEG_RSQ = 2) as risk_2,
       sum(mt_dem) filter (where NB_DEG_RSQ = 3) as risk_3,
       sum(mt_dem) filter (where NB_DEG_RSQ = 4) as risk_4
from (       
  SELECT D.NO_PTF, C.NB_DEG_RSQ, D.MT_DEM/100 as MT_DEM
  FROM public.TB_Demande      D
    INNER JOIN public.TB_Compartiment C 
       ON D.ID_CPA = C.ID_CPA
      AND D.MC_UTL = 'F3000'
      AND C.IN_ACT = true
)      
GROUP BY no_ptf;
```

Comment: Even in SQL Server, filtered aggregation is possible and often *preferable* compared to PIVOT. The amount of code is similar in both cases, but I'm pretty sure *nobody* can remember how to write a PIVOT without checking the docs. I suspect UNPIVOT (a really useful command) was created first, then someone said "that was too easy, why not add a PIVOT?"